# Applicativeを使って複数の文字列を結合するにはどうすればいいですか

Tags: haskell

アプリカティブスタイルで

```
(++) <$> Just "a" <*> Just "b" -- = Just "ab"
```

のような例がよくありますが、これを

```
(++) <$> Just "a" <*> Just "b" <*> Just "c" <*> ... -- Just "abc...
```

と繋げていくように記載することは出来ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

```
(++) <$> Just "a" <*> Just "b" -- = Just "ab"
```

で、Maybe String が二つしか連結できないのは、そもそも元の`(++)`が引数を二つしか取れないからです。別の言い方をすれば、`(++) "a" "b"`をMaybeアプリカティブにしたものが上の式です。

`(++)`単独では任意の個数の文字列をとることができないので、まずアプリカティブにする前に、素の文字列で任意の個数の文字列を連結する方法を考えます。

```
foldl1 (++) ["a", "b", "c"] -- = "abc"
```

あとは、文字列と関数をアプリカティブにします。

```
foldl1 (liftA2 (++)) [Just "a", Just "b", Just "c"] -- = Just "abc"
foldl1 (liftA2 (++)) [Just "a", Nothing, Just "c"] -- = Nothing
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。foldだと綺麗ですね。しかし、私としては２つの引数をとる関数を使って、リストを使わずに f <x> Just "a" <y> Just "b" <y>  Just "c" <y> ... のように記載出来る方法が知りたいです。